# Composer minimum stability issue

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to make an extension for Flarum forum. On composer.json, I added the following lines.

```
"minimum-stability": "beta",
"prefer-stable": true
```

When I run `composer require evaldasl/flarum-ext-lithuanian` I get the following error.

> Could not find package evaldasl/flarum-ext-lithuanan at any version for your minimum-stability (beta). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

How do I avoid that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/), I can see that it's not registered yet. Even though you have [signed up and submitted](https://packagist.org/packages/evaldasl/) your [other Github project](https://github.com/EvaldasL?tab=repositories), it doesn't automatically list all your projects. You must [submit each one](https://packagist.org/packages/submit).

Also note that there's already [a project registered by this same name](https://packagist.org/packages/pavelas/flarum-ext-lithuanian), so it might be considered a fork.

> Do not submit forks of existing packages. If you need to test changes to a package that you forked to patch, use VCS Repositories instead. If however it is a real long-term fork you intend on maintaining feel free to submit it.

Once you submit, then your composer require command will work.